# Reading strings from a excel

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Please go easy on me this is my first post.
So I am try to read data from an excel sheet and store it in two `string` arrays but the arrays stay empty and I can't figure out why.

After all the loops execute the arrays are still empty but if a put in a `println` inside the loop the `string` is printed but the array is still empty.

Here is my code:

```
package excell;

import jxl.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

/**
 *
 * @author Keanu
 */
public class Excell {

    static void read(String input) throws IOException {
        int size = 0;
        Sheet sheet = null;
        FileInputStream file;
        Workbook w;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(input);
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
            sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            size = sheet.getRows() * 3;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("NOT here");
        } catch (BiffException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Excell.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String[] productName = new String[size];
        String[] productURL = new String[size];

        for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) {
            for (int x = 4; x < sheet.getRows(); x++) {
                productName[j] = sheet.getCell(0, x).getContents();
            }

        }

        for (int j = 399; j < sheet.getRows() * 2; j++) {
            for (int x = 4; x < sheet.getRows(); x++) {
                productName[j] = sheet.getCell(2, x).getContents();
                //System.out.println(productName[j]);

            }

        }

        for (int j = 399 * 2; j < sheet.getRows() * 3; j++) {
            for (int x = 4; x < sheet.getRows(); x++) {
                productName[j] = sheet.getCell(4, x).getContents();
                //System.out.println(productName[j]);
            }

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) {
            for (int x = 4; x < sheet.getRows(); x++) {
                productURL[j] = sheet.getCell(1, x).getContents();
            }

        }
        for (int j = 399; j < sheet.getRows() * 2; j++) {
            for (int x = 4; x < sheet.getRows(); x++) {
                productURL[j] = sheet.getCell(3, x).getContents();

            }
        }
        for (int j = 399 * 2; j < sheet.getRows() * 3; j++) {
            for (int x = 4; x < sheet.getRows(); x++) {
                productURL[j] = sheet.getCell(5, x).getContents();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(productName));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(productURL));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] productName = {};
        String[] ProductURL = {};
        try {
            read("Price_Script.xls");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Excell.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

This is my output:

```
Warning:  Cannot determine link type
[, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]
[, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this piece of code:

for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) {
            for (int x = 4; x < sheet.getRows(); x++) {
                productName[j] = sheet.getCell(0, x).getContents();
            }

        }???

Comment: What do you think happens to the existing value of `productName[j]` the second time through the inner loop, when you assign it a new value?

Comment: Thank you That was the problem.